# How can I attach dataframes to an R-script?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am currently writing on my thesis and am doing some calculations with R for it. I am supposed to hand in the script I used and would also like to hand in the .csv-files I used.
What I would currently do is delete the path where the .csv-files are imported, and write something like "add path here" to make clear that the person looking at the script knows to put their own personal path where they have stored the files. 
I feel like this is a very inelegant solution and would like bypass the part where they have to import the files.

Is there any way to attach the dataframes to the script already? Maybe there is some way I can make my dataframes a "staple" in R like the tables of soya-sperm counts, i.e. 
Thanks for any proposals!

Comment: The recommended approach in R is to build a package. A package contains code and can contain data.

Comment: Just wondering if the "project" structure from RStudio might be interesting here. Maybe easier to handle than packages and allow the use of relative path i.e. you can have a `data` folder in the project and have your script look into this folder to find specific files. It also helps to keep raw data, scripts and outputs separated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standard approach but an approach that you can consider to "attach" the dataframes in a script is by using `dput` function. This can make your script look ugly if your dataframe is huge or have more columns in which case you can create another script with the `dput` output and `source` it in your main script to have the data.

As an example, let's say you have your data imported in R, call it `df`. Create a script `data.R` which has output of `dput(df)`. So if your dataframe is  `df <- data.frame(a = 10, b = sample(10))`. `data.R` could contain

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), 
    b = c(6L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Now in your main script you can use `source(data.R)` and the data would be present in this script to use in the variable `df`.